# Push input fields to array and loop through

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, foreach

I'd like to add some input fields from my table (specific row) to an array. Later I want to loop through this array.

I do it like this:

```
selectedObjects.forEach((tr) => {
    cell = tr.find('input');

    cell.each(function() {
       arr.push($(this));
    });
});
```

arr shows something like:

```
0 S [<input type="text">] (1)
1 S [<input type="text">] (1)
```

I try to loop through arr like this. PS: I should be able to loop through **arr = $('form input')** too (with the same function).

```
arr.each(function() {
    console.log(this.name)
});
```

Error: arr.each is not a function

Comment: This should work fine. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should make `arr` a jQuery object:

```
$(arr)
```

Doing so, you would have access to the [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

So you have to try this:

```
$(arr).each(function() {
    console.log(this.name)
});
```

The reason why you have to do this is the fact that `each` is a function defined on the jQuery object.

Comment: Works absolutly fine, but if I push an input with `name=name[]` to `arr` using `cell.find('input')` and log cell.name it shows undefined. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) in main post to show the issue happening. Then others can debug it and provide more help.

Comment: @Lupin I agree with ^^^, it is a bit difficult to find a solution to this problem without having the corresponding HTML.